# I am trying to execute a small String which contains a powershell script using -Command option but its not getting executed? how to resolve this?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm, powershell-core

I'm using PowerShell Core to do this.
The command :

```
pwsh -NoLogo -NonInteractive -InputFormat text -OutputFormat text -Command “& { $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'pswd' -AsPlainText -Force;$skipCN = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck -SkipCACheck;$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential 'Administrator’ , $Password;Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -Authentication Basic -Credential $remote_credential -ScriptBlock {{ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory | Format-List * }} -useSSL -SessionOption $skipCN }”
```

and the output is:[image: Command and output]

however, if I run the script using command

```
pwsh -NoLogo -NonInteractive -InputFormat text -OutputFormat text -Command absolute_file_path
```

It work's as expected.

What changes should I make to make it run as a string using -Command option?

Edit: removing the double `{{` after `-scriptblock` and replacing it with a single `{`  did not help.

Comment: For one thing, stop using curly quotes (especially don't mix them as in `'Administrator’`) but straight ones. These so-called 'smart-quotes' may look nice in a Word document, but can do weird things in code. Also, I would advise you to not cram everything into one single line of code, which makes debugging extremely hard to do.

Comment: @Theo I tried using straight quotes but it did not work, and this entire code is passed on as a string and each line is separated by a  semicolon ' ; ' .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra curly brackets in the script block, and use the straight quotes.

```
pwsh -NoLogo -NonInteractive -InputFormat text -OutputFormat text -Command "& { $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'pswd' -AsPlainText -Force;$skipCN = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck -SkipCACheck;$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential 'Administrator' , $Password;Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -Authentication Basic -Credential $remote_credential -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory | Format-List * } -useSSL -SessionOption $skipCN }"
```

If pwsh does not work, replace with powershell.

Comment: Smith,  still no luck on it, I am getting the following error.





ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  … ct System.Management.Automation.PsCredential 'Administrator',;Invoke- …
     |                                                                 ~
     | Missing expression after ',' in pipeline element.

Comment: In your script you are creating $Credential and later using $remote_credential. Is that a typo, or is there more to your script than posted?

Comment: yes it was a typo, fixed it still won't work, it's failing on this line I believe "$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential 'Administrator' , $Password" 

I guess it's not picking up the value of $Password and  maybe that's why it's printing

ParserError: Line | 1 | … ct System.Management.Automation.PsCredential 'Administrator',;Invoke- … | ~ | Missing expression after ',' in pipeline element. –

Comment: Have you tested this from within PowerShell? If not, open a PowerShell and paste the code between the curly brackets and see if works. You could test each line of code (between the ";") one at a time and see which line causes the error.

Comment: Hi @Mike Smith, I am actually using this script to get the wmi-object from the remote computer. So yes it works.

Comment: For the benefit of others looking at this question, could you tell us more about what you are wanting to do? It looks like you are remoting from a Linux box to a Windows box. Which versions of PowerShell and operating system are on each? Have other remoting attempts been successful? I.e. Is the problem the current request to the remote machine, or an issue with remoting.

Comment: Hi @Mike Smith - MCT - MVP,  sorry for the delay, I the above example, I am trying to get wmi data of a remote windows host from a linux device.  The command line which I posted is actually a script and works fine when I execute it as a script in powershell core.   I am actually trying to execute the script in a non-interactive way i.e without opening the powershell window and only using the command line.
I have no problem in remoting using powershell core, the issue is I can't make this command to run on the terminal.